# SQL to Insert Repeat Rows per Record in Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need help in adding blank rows in a query result so that the ending result will have consistent repeat values to use in a template. For example, I have a query the returns the amount of sales by customer and quarter. If a customer didn't have a sale in a given quarter, the quarter naturally does not show. However I need it to.

Here's an example of what I mean (EDIT: The second table was wrong in the original):

[image]

EDIT: 
I've added sample create table and insert into scripts related to the suggestions below to use for testing.

```
create table #customers (id int, customer varchar(30));
create table #quarters (id int, quarter varchar(30));
create table #salesAggs (id int, customer varchar(30), quarter varchar(30), amount int);

insert into #customers (id, customer) values (1, 'John'), (2, 'Mary'), (3, 'Kathy');
insert into #quarters (id, quarter) values (1, 'Q1'), (2, 'Q2'), (3, 'Q3'), (4, 'Q4');
insert into #salesAggs (id, customer, quarter, amount)
values
    (1, 'John', 'Q1', 10),
    (2, 'John', 'Q3', 10),
    (3, 'Mary', 'Q2', 10),
    (4, 'Kathy', 'Q1', 10)
;
```

Comment: Having quarters with no years is suspicious.

Comment: This is just a basic example to demonstrate the concept. The real solution has years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a cross join between quarters and customers before joining it to your sales data:

```
select     c.id, c.customer, q.quarter, sa.amount
from       quarters q
cross join customers c
left join  salesAggs sa on q.quarter = sa.quarter and c.id = sa.id
```

If you don't have such tables (though you should), simulate them:

```
select     c.id, c.customer, q.quarter, sa.amount
from       (select distinct quarter from salesAggs) q
cross join (select distinct id, customer from salesAggs) c
left join  salesAggs sa on q.quarter = sa.quarter and c.id = sa.id
```

If you're aggregating in the same step:

```
select     c.id, c.customer, q.quarter, sum(s.amount) as amount
from       quarters q
cross join customers c
left join  sales s on q.quarter = s.quarter and c.id = s.id 
group by   c.id, c.customer, q.quarter
```

---

#### Edit: Example to match sample data later provided by OP

Given the structure of the tables you actually added, you would need to change the column names you're joining on:

```
select     c.id, c.customer, q.quarter, sa.amount
from       #quarters q
cross join #customers c
left join  #salesAggs sa on q.quarter = sa.quarter and c.customer = sa.customer
```

By the way, you've tagged Postgre, but it seems you're using Sql Server.

Comment: Just for emphasis, the instinct to add junk data to "fill in the blanks" for your required output is understandable, but it leads to real headaches later. One of the beauty parts of SQL is that you can join the data you have against a "grid" of data you're interested in, and let the left join "fill in the blanks." So, if you've got timestamps and want every day, you can generate a series of days, and then the left join leaves you with each day and fills in the "slots" where your actual data matches. No junk data. Now you want 8 hour shifts instead of days? No problem, left join against that.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, your "grid" that you join against can be a table, but doesn't have to be. A table, view, set returning function, generate_series() output and more.

Comment: I understand the add junk or sparse data isn't generally best practice. But, just need to let that go. This is what is needed in this instance.Thanks Morris

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution pwilcox. I'm looking into and will report back

Comment: This does not work. I've added sample create table and insert into scripts to use against your suggestion to demonstrate it.

Comment: Use `c.id = sa.customer`.

Comment: @shawnt00, close, its `c.customer = sa.customer`.  Added an edit to meet the newly provided data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all the values you want in the original data.  You can generate them on the fly:

```
select c.id, c.customer, q.quarter, sa.amount
from (select distinct id, customer from salesAggs
     ) c cross join 
     (select 'Q1' as quarter union all
      select 'Q2' as quarter union all
      select 'Q3' as quarter union all
      select 'Q4' as quarter
     ) q left join 
     salesAggs sa
     on q.quarter = sa.quarter and c.id = sa.id;
```

In Postgres, this is simpler:

```
select c.id, c.customer, q.quarter, sa.amount
from (select distinct id, customer from salesAggs
     ) c cross join 
     (values ('Q1'), ('Q2'), ('Q3'), ('Q4')
     ) q(quarter) left join 
     salesAggs sa
     on q.quarter = sa.quarter and c.id = sa.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e1c40341c2318639c6ea0f46877f2fed) is a db<>fiddle *using Postgres* that shows the two queries.

Comment: This does not work. I've added sample create table and insert into scripts to use against your suggestion to demonstrate it.

Comment: @ptownbro . . . If you have tables with the data, then you should use pwilcox's solution.

Comment: The problem is in the join condition `c.id = sa.customer`, based on the tables posts after you answered.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and this is still not correct. It should return 12 rows not 16. It may be miscommunication by me because the original image I used was wrong. I fixed it.